# Javascript gallery with two items at a time

Tags: javascript

I have this gallery that shows two items at a time, but I was wondering if there's a more elegant way than repeating the same code all the time for the item B in the gallery.

Here's the main code:

```
var Gallery = new Object();
    window.onload = function(){
Gallery.Images = ['red','blue','pink','green','yellow','purple','orange','navy'];
Gallery.CurrentIndexA = 0;
    Gallery.CurrentIndexB = 1;
 };

Gallery.Next = function(){
if (Gallery.CurrentIndexA < (Gallery.Images.length-1)){ 
    Gallery.CurrentIndexA++;
    Gallery.CurrentIndexB++;
    console.log("A is:" + Gallery.CurrentIndexA);
    console.log("B is:" + Gallery.CurrentIndexB);
} 
else {
    Gallery.CurrentIndexA = 0;
}
Gallery.Display();
};

Gallery.Prev = function(){
if (Gallery.CurrentIndexA > 0){
    Gallery.CurrentIndexA--;
    Gallery.CurrentIndexB--;
    console.log("A is:" + Gallery.CurrentIndexA);
    console.log("B is:" + Gallery.CurrentIndexB);
}
else {
    Gallery.CurrentIndexA = (Gallery.Images.length-1); 
}
Gallery.Display();
};

Gallery.Display = function(){
var photoA = document.getElementById('photoA');
var photoB = document.getElementById('photoB');
var currentImageA = Gallery.Images[Gallery.CurrentIndexA];
var currentImageB = Gallery.Images[Gallery.CurrentIndexB];
photoA.className = currentImageA;
photoB.className = currentImageB;
};
```

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2AdA9/1/

Thanks very much!

Comment: Your fiddle does not work.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make it look better one thing you could do is something like this.

```
Gallery.moveUp = function (){
    Gallery.CurrentIndexA += 1;
    Gallery.CurrentIndexB += 1;
};

Gallery.moveDown = function (){
    Gallery.CurrentIndexA -= 1;
    Gallery.CurrentIndexB -= 1;
};
```

Then just call those functions when you want to move up or move back.